# Как лучше организовать перехват исключения C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс, содержащий поля типа int. Значения вводятся посредством textBox.
Суть в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, вызывается конструктор класса и значения textBox, если их можно преобразовать в int передаются в конструктор в качестве аргументов для параметров.

Куда лучше определить исключение вне конструктора или в нем? Не хочу громоздкий и неаккуратный код. Мое мнение таково, что желательно конструктор сделать по возможности более кратким.

Может быть, не совсем точно выразился, что ж, написал как смог.

Comment: Приведите код класса и пример его иницализации.

Comment: Перехвата исключений должно быть вовсе как можно меньше. Хотите из текстбокса в int перевести, сделайте метод, который будет делать что то на подобие `if (int.TryParse(stringValue) out var result) {return result} else {//Логируем если надо невозможность перевести в int}` и все,  вызывайте этот метод где надо, пусть он сам все сделает за вас. Можете вовсе сделать его расширением, тогда вовсе будете вызывать `myTextBox.Text.ToInt();`.

Comment: Чтоб избежать исключений используйте `int.TryParse()`, а еще лучше привязки.

Comment: Проверку допустимости введенных значений и преобразование типов делайте в вызывающем коде до вызова конструктора. В конструкторе имеет смысл проверять только логическую допустимость значения, если такие ограничения есть, например, что полученное число больше нуля.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Какой именно GUI-фреймкворк используете? Нет ли там компонента, предназначенного для ввода чисел? Например, в WinForms есть [NumericUpDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.8), который можно настроить на ввод целых чисел.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю о нем.